# displaying a colored 2d array in matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib

I'd like to plot a 2-d matrix from numpy as a colored matrix in Matplotlib.  I have the following 9-by-9 array:

```
my_array = diag(ones(9))

# plot the array
pcolor(my_array)
```

I'd like to set the first three elements of the diagonal to be a certain color, the next three to be a different color, and the last three a different color.  I'd like to specify the color by a hex code string, like "#FF8C00".  How can I do this?

Also, how can I set the color of 0-valued elements for pcolor?

Answer (score 2):

To have the elements be different colors, assign them different values:

```
my_array = diag([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
```

To specify the colors, try:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, NoNorm
cmap = ListedColormap(['#E0E0E0', '#FF8C00', '#8c00FF', '#00FF8C'])
pcolor(my_array,cmap=cmap,norm=NoNorm())
```

The `norm=NoNorm()` argument avoids any scaling of the matrix values, so that 0 gets the first color in the list, 1 the second, etc.